# Javascript search and replace inside of CSS

Tags: javascript, css, search, replace

Is there a way to replace some values inside of a loaded css file?

For example I have some css files loaded and I don't know its classes but I want to replace all the values that contain #FFFFFF with #000000 and also take effect immediately on the webpage.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want to do this specifically? This seems a bit hacky, and I can't help but wonder if there's a better, more practical method to achieve the same result.

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this will do what you'd like.  Put it in a script tag at the top of your page.  I don't suggest this as a solution because it will go through all the elements on your page to figure out which ones to change, and change those that it found.

**Updated**, missed the ); at the end.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('*').filter(function() { 
        return $(this).css('background-color') == "rgb(255, 255, 255)" 
    }).css('background-color', '#000')
});
```